# How to create "when a HTTP Request is received" on (My folder with files ) placed in Azure Data Lake

Tags: power-automate

How to create "when a HTTP Request is received" on (My folder with files ) placed in Azure Data Lake
2 seconds ago
Hi Friends,

I have Azure Data lake path where business system / Users placing a folder with files on a monthly basis . I want to create a "When a HTTP request is received " then when ever the folder is placed  then i want to run the further steps in power automate'

How to read the folders on azure data lake received files then execute the HTTP Request.

Thanks